# How is a partial audio file played?

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio

How would I play an audio file in javascript that has been spliced into two byte arrays and loaded separately from a server at different times? I want to load the first half of an mp3 file, then, while the mp3 is playing, load the second half and seamlessly continue playing through the whole file.

Answer (score 0):

While the first part is playing, create another audio tag to pre-load the second half, but do not play it.

```
<audio src="the second half.mp3” preload="auto"></audio>
```

When the first audio trigger the ended event, change its URL to the second half.

The browser will get the file from cache and starts to play it immediately.

Sorry for my poor English, hoping this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `canplaythrough` and `ended` events to, play the first audio while loading the second, then play the second after loading. Something like this:

```js
var canPlayAudio2 = false;
var audio1Ended = false;

var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src = "your_audio_source";
audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
  //after first audio loads, start loading second audio
  var audio2 = document.createElement('audio');
  audio2.src = "your_audio2_source";
  audio2.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function() {
    canPlayAudio2 = true;
    if (audio1Ended) {
      audio2.play();
    }
  });

  //play the first audio, play second audio if availible once finished
  audio.play();
  audio.addEventListener('ended', function() {
    audio1Ended = true;
    if (canPlayAudio2) {
      audio2.play();
    }
  });

});
```